# Adding values permently in a switch case to a variable outside the switch case

Tags: php, json

I am trying to save the data from a JSON file per hour, the file is always updating itself (API). Though I can't get it to work.

My code:

```
    //Mid way update
$time = date("H:i");

$midWay = " </br>";


switch ($time) {
  case '16:45':
    $midWay = $data['E-Today'] ['value'];
    break;

  default:
    # code...
    break;
}

echo $midWay;
```

What I want to achieve is everytime a certain time comes by (for example 12pm). The value of $data['E-Today'] ['value'] gets added to the variable midWay. The value of $data['E-Today'] ['value'] is always updating and I want to be able to track the value per hour. The issue I have now is everytime when it's a different time, it's not in the variable or something anymore

Comment: You know `$time = date("H:i");` is the same as your $time....

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking for in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you :)

What I want to achieve is everytime a certain time comes by (for example 12pm). The value of $data['E-Today'] ['value'] gets added to the variable midWay.

The issue I have now is everytime when it's a different time, it's not in the variable or something anymore.

Comment: You mean ever time the file runs the previous data is not there? That is how php works. It doesn't save anything unless you tell it to save the data. If that is what you want just tell me and I will help you.

Comment: Also remember that php can't run a certain time by itself. You need a cronejob for that

Comment: That's exactly what I need it to do yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method that is quite simple. Read and save the data to a text file.

```
//Mid way update

switch (date("H:i")) { // removed $time, is it needed elsewhere you can just add it again
  case '16:45':
    if(file_exists("jsondata.txt")){
         $midWay = file_get_contents("jsondata.txt"); // Read the old data from text file to $midWay
    }else{ $midWay = "";}  // if jsondata.txt does not exists (first time you run the code)

    $midWay .= " </br>" . $data['E-Today'] ['value']; // Add new data to string. ".=" means append
    // I believe this is a better solution but you need to test and see
    //$midWay .= PHP.EOL . $data['E-Today'] ['value'];  // PHP.EOL means new line <br> is a html tag that wont work in a text file.

    file_put_contets("jsondata.txt", $midWay); // Update the text file with new data.
    break;

  default:
    # code...
    break;
}

echo $midWay;
```

This code will not run by itself.
You will need a cron job to run the file or keep a computer running that runs the file every x minutes.

Comment: $data['E-Today'] ['value'] this data is out of a json object. Doesn't that needs to be added somewhere in the code?

Also this script needs to be in a seperate file right?

Comment: @Samuel That value is in the code. What do you mean by separate file?

Comment: I am making a program that reads of a JSON file - this is a part of the program that I can't get to work myself. So this script can it run inside a script or does it need to be a stand alone script.

Also I can't really get it to work properly, if you could tell me some more information on how to get it to work that would be great.

Though I want to thank you for your time already, I really appriciate it :)

Comment: The reason you can't get it to work is because you have commented the code out. Uncomment the code and it will run. You can have it running inside this as you have I think. But again. Since you only want it to run at 16:45 you either have to run it yourself or have a cronjob do it.